# Element missing in the first column of the first row when reading CSV in java

Tags: java, char, read.csv

I have a csv file:

```
A,1
B,2
C,3
```

Whenever I try to get the character of the first column of the first row using .charAt(0), it return nothing.

I tried to read the csv row by row and print the whole row and the element in the first column, the expected result to get this:

```
[A,1]
A
[B,2]
B
[C,3]
C
```

However, I got this as output, first element in first row went missing:

```
[A,1]

[B,2]
B
[C,3]
C
```

This is my code:

```
package application;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class trail {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  String file = "src/Book4.csv";
  BufferedReader reader = null;
  String line = "";
  


  
  try {
      reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          String[] row = line.split(",");           
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
          System.out.println(row[0].charAt(0));
          
                         
      }
  } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
      try {
          reader.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
  
    
 }
 
 
 
}
```

But if i change the `System.out.println(row[0].charAt(0));`  to `System.out.println(row[0]);` , it output correctly, but I need the element as char later.

Comment: Make sure your input file is not saved with a Byte Order Marker (BOM). Java `Reader`s don't process them as special

Comment: `System.out.printf("%04x%n", (int)row[0].charAt(0));` might be interesting

Comment: @g00se Hum... so strange, it suddenly work after I open the csv with "text edit" app and save again (I used excel before, I think that's the cause because I tried with duplication of the file and the error occur again). But I tried your code, before it worked, for the missing "A", I get "feff" which is different from other I got number such as 0042 ......

Comment: *I get "feff"* That's the BOM